# Angular 5 + Swagger Codegen && Strict Null Checks

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, swagger-codegen

In tsconfig.json of my angular-cli (latest) project (ng v5 LTS) I have set (and have to keep it)

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
```

I use Swagger Codegen (Maven v2.3.1) to generate api client models. The command is using those options:

```
`-jar ${jarPath} generate -i ${apiPath} -l typescript-angular -o ${outputPath} --type-mappings Date=string -D withInterfaces=true --additional-properties ngVersion=5`
```

In .angular-cli.json I exclude the generated files from linting like:

```
  ...,
  "lint": [
    {
      ...
      "exclude": ["**/swagger/**"]
    }, ...
```

When I do 'ng serve' or 'ng build', I get multiple

```
error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'
```

for generated configuration object. Like this one:

```
...
import { Configuration } from '../configuration';
...
if (this.configuration.apiKeys["Authorization"]) {
    headers = headers.set('Authorization',
    this.configuration.apiKeys["Authorization"]);
}
...
```

I tried to exclude generated swagger files in tslint.json and tsconfig extensions as well with no luck.

Is there a way to set Swagger Codegen to produce files which pass strict null checks or to set Angular CLI to omit linting of swagger files during aot compilation?

NOTE: I have to use AOT compilation.

---

*The only solution I can think of is to programatically replace all instances of*

```
if (this.configuration.apiKeys["Authorization"])
```

*with*

```
if (this.configuration.apiKeys && this.configuration.apiKeys["Authorization"])
```

or objectHasOwnProperty or similar evaluation ... but that sounds as a brut force strategy ...

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic TypeScript solution if in fact `apiKeys` is *always* defined is to use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html),

> A new `!` post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its
>   operand is non-`null` and non-`undefined` in contexts where the type
>   checker is unable to conclude that fact. Specifically, the operation
>   `x!` produces a value of the type of `x` with `null` and `undefined` excluded.

So in your case:

```
if (this.configuration.!apiKeys["Authorization"]) { ... }
```

That said, using a `.hasOwnProperty()` check is not a bad pattern either: it's idiomatic JavaScript.

(I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Swagger Codegen, perhaps someone else can provide a useful answer for your upstream workflow.)

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this operator, however, that has no effect on my problem, since I do not want to rewrite already generated code -> I rather prefer to generate the correct code.

Comment: @NoobSwag You may not, but as someone who's been active here for over 9 years, I can guarantee that someone will eventually stumble across this thanks to a search engine. That notwithstanding, I'm curious for a suitable solution to your problem as well, though the only available one might be to change your generated configuration file. :(